# Adding content into existing element node, expecting the result to be `Region 6` but instead got 'Region<span>6</span>'

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and is learning how to add new content into existing html. In the code below, i'm trying to count the number of `li` in the DOM and display the total number to an existing `h2` element.

I was expecting the result to be `Region 6` but instead I have got

[image]

Because I just started learning JavaScript, I'm not sure what I did wrong.

[image]

Comment: Is there a SQL question here?

Comment: If you don't show your HTML we can't answer for sure, but I'd hazard a guess that you have a newline between the parent element's opening tag and the `<span>` descendant, in which case the `firstChild` is a `textNode` not the `<span>`. You should, perhaps, have used `heading.firstElementChild.nodeValue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you used `.textContent` to set the text to `"<span>" + totalItems + "</span>"`.

The [docs for textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) state: "... the text is not parsed as HTML ... Moreover, this avoids an XSS attack vector.".

You might want to use `.innerHTML` instead, but be cautions as it can make your site vulnerable to cross-site scripting.